# Including libraries while cross-compiling using Mingw-w64 on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, mingw-w64

I'm trying to cross-compile a program with the following libraries:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <gmp.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>
```

Due to the nature of the project, the source is compiled to download. The server runs Ubuntu 18.04. I've succeeded in employing this using `mingw-w64` on less complex programs by running:

`x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ api_1.cpp -o api_1.exe -std=c++11 -static`

This fails when I run it on the above example with:

```
api_1.cpp:3:10: fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <curl/curl.h>
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Without `#include <curl/curl.h>`, `#include <gmp.h>` fails.

Looking in `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include`, neither of those libraries are there. How do I add additional libraries to `mingw-w64`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy day.

Download source tarball. Extract:

`tar zxvf mylibrary.tar.gz`

`cd mylibrary`

`./configure --target x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32`

Compile:

`x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ myprogram.cpp -o myprogram.exe -std=c++11 -static`